# How do I install a working version of Standard ML on Mac?

Tags: functional-programming, sml, smlnj

I'm using Mac OSX 10.7.5 and I can't seem to get download a working Standard ML compiler with a REPL available.  Is this supposed to be so difficult?  Is there a best ML that I should be downloading.  I've tried SML/NJ and MLton to no avail.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20009628/sml-not-detecting-os-on-os-x-mavericks The given link contains the answer too.

Answer (score 11):

A Mac user can also use

```
$ brew install smlnj
```

Add path similar to `/usr/local/Cellar/smlnj/110.82/libexec/bin` to your .bash_profile.

```
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

See [this article](http://islovely.co/posts/painless-installation-of-sml-on-os-x/) for more information.

Comment: For SML/NJ, this answer should be preferred today.

Answer (score 5):

I did the following:

--download appropriate(for your operating system) .dmg file from     http://www.smlnj.org/dist/working/110.75/

--in your ~/.bash_profile:    export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/smlnj-110.75/bin"

--run your bash_profile by doing source .bash_profile

--go to terminal and type sml.

I personally use sml mode for emacs. Add the following to your .emacs file and make sure that sml mode is installed in your emacs from M-list-packages.

(setenv "PATH" (concat "/usr/local/smlnj-110.75/bin:" (getenv "PATH")))

(setq exec-path (cons "/usr/local/smlnj-110.75/bin" exec-path))

You can start sml REPL in emacs by doing C-c C-s.

Comment: Thanks.  I got it to work using an SML called Poly.  Have you heard of it?  I'm hoping it's just as good as NJML

Comment: Poly/ML is notoriously unknown, but much better than SML/NJ: faster compiler producing faster code.

Comment: Thanks, I encountered some problems on Mavericks when following your instructions. The binary from http://smlnj.org errors out  when installing on Mavericks. Luckily, adding a line in `/usr/local/smlnj-110.75/config/_arch-n-opsys` as instructed [here](http://users-cs.au.dk/danvy/dIFP09/smlnj/Mac-OS-X-Snow-Leopard-install-smlnj.txt) solved the install problem. Emacs package worked fine except that C-c C-s does not do anything. Also, you probably mean `M-x list-packages` instead of `M-list-packages`.

Answer (score 5):

I downloaded SML/NJ 110.76 for Mac OS X package from http://www.smlnj.org/dist/working/110.76/index.html

and then installed it, and access it at `/usr/local/smlnj/bin/sml`

Answer (score 2):

You can try Moscow ML from http://mosml.org/ - there is also a [mosml-2.10.1.pkg](https://github.com/kfl/mosml/releases/download/ver-2.10.1/mosml-2.10.1.pkg) available for OS X. Moscow ML is generally less popular than SML/NJ but has a very fine REPL with comprehensible error messages. It is an excellent learning environment.

Answer (score 2):

[Poly/ML](https://www.polyml.org) works well for me on M1 Mac. I installed it with:

```
brew install polyml
```

Answer (score 0):

for the m1 and m2 users, in addition to the @Tai 's answer

```
$ brew install smlnj
```

after above command.

for me, the path was;

> /usr/local//smlnj/bin

instead of ~/.bash_profile  file edit the ~/.zshrc

if you do not have create one with;

```
touch ~/.zshrc

open -t ~/.zshrc
```

put the below at the end of file ;

> export PATH=/usr/local//smlnj/bin:$PATH

save and run the below or logout user;

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Answer (score 0):

The current supported "legacy" version of SML/NJ is 110.99.3 and is available at smlnj.org.  For macOS, try one of the macOS installer packages:

smlnj-x86-110.99.3.pkg  (32-bits)
smlnj-amd64-110.99.3.pkg  (64 bits)

You will probably want the 64-bit amd64 package on a reasonably recent Mac (and any Mac running macOS 10.15 (Catalina) or later, since 32-bit apps are no longer supported by Catalina and later versions).  If you are on an Apple Silicon Mac (using an M1 or M2 processor), 110.99.3 will run under Rosetta 2. An ARM native version is under development and will be announced at some point.

See smlnj.org or GitHub.com/smlnj or standardml.zulipchat.com for announcements or further information.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't mind a somewhat big download using approx. 600 MB disk space, you can try Isabelle/ML.  Isabelle is mainly a theorem proving environment, but it is based on Poly/ML including a reasonably IDE: Isabelle/jEdit.

To write SML in Isabelle/ML, it needs to be incorporated into theory sources like this:

```
theory Scratch
imports Main
begin

ML {* fun f 0 = 1 | f n = n * f (n - 1) *}

ML {* f 42 *}

end
```