# SML not detecting OS on OS X Mavericks

Tags: sml, osx-mavericks, smlnj

I could not run SMLNJ on Mavericks
It shows me the error

```
sml: unable to determine architecture/operating system
```

I also looked in /usr/local/smlnj/config/_arch-n-opsys file and Mavericks is mentioned there.

```
13*) OPSYS=darwin;  HEAP_OPSYS=darwin ;; # MacOS X 10.9 Mavericks
```

Can some one help me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this [.pkg file](http://smlnj.cs.uchicago.edu/dist/working/110.76/smlnj-x86-110.76.pkg) to reinstall the SML and see if the problem happens again.

Comment: thanx... it worked this way. I want to ask one more thing - from where do we need to set up the path so that I can start sml on terminal just by typing sml, for now I have to type /usr/local/smlnj/bin/sml

Comment: You can set up the path for current user by adding `export PATH=/usr/local/smlnj/bin:$PATH` in the file `~/.bash_profile`

Comment: I am sorry I am completely new to this... plz tell me where this file lies?

Comment: Open Terminal, use `nano ~/.bash_profile` to open the file with nano. Then you can add the path and save it. If you don't have the file, it will be created. The next time you login, the path will be effective. If you want it be effective immediately, use the command `source ~/.bash_profile`.