# SML/NJ not autoloading Basis library on Mac

Tags: sml, smlnj

When I try to use the function `List.nth`, the sml shell returns this error message:

```
- List.nth([1,2,3],0);
[autoloading]

unexpected exception (bug?) in SML/NJ: Io [Io: openIn failed on "/Users/jhr/Work/smlnj/osx-dist/smlnj.dst/sml.boot.x86-unix/smlnj/basis/.cm/x86-unix/basis.cm", No such file or directory]
raised at: Basis/Implementation/IO/bin-io-fn.sml:617.25-617.71
         ../cm/util/safeio.sml:30.11
         ../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:42.54
```

It returns same error message if I use `nth` without `List.` as well.
So I can guess that there is something problem with 'autoloading' the library.

But there are some strange things more.
If I use another basis library function `length`, it works fine. Like this:

```
- length ([1,2,3]);
val it = 3 : int
```

But what if I use `List.length`? It goes to error. Like this:

```
- List.length([1,2,3]);
[autoloading]

unexpected exception (bug?) in SML/NJ: Io [Io: openIn failed on "/Users/jhr/Work/smlnj/osx-dist/smlnj.dst/sml.boot.x86-unix/smlnj/basis/.cm/x86-unix/basis.cm", No such file or directory]
 raised at: Basis/Implementation/IO/bin-io-fn.sml:617.25-617.71
         ../cm/util/safeio.sml:30.11
         ../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:42.54
```

So it seems there is definitely something wrong with 'autoloading' stuff, but I can't figure out how to fix it.
Please help me finding the problem and fixing it!

Note:

1. I use Max OS X 10.13.3, and SML/NJ compiler of v110.81
2. 'jhr' in the path is the previous 'user name'. I changed to 'cadenzah'. That is why that path does not exist. There is 'cadenzah' directory in 'Users' directory.

ps. Maybe there is something problem with directory structure of complier itself between previous version and this(v110.81)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install a working version of Standard ML on Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19024116/how-do-i-install-a-working-version-of-standard-ml-on-mac)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you install SML/NJ on your Mac?

It seems that the compiler resides in a user-owned directory; I would recommend that you try and install SML/NJ via Homebrew as [this blog post](http://islovely.co/posts/painless-installation-of-sml-on-os-x/) instructs:

```
$ ruby <(curl -fsSk https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)
$ brew update
$ brew install smlnj
```

Since you're not asking how to install SML/NJ, this isn't a duplicate of the following questions:

- [SML not detecting OS on OS X Mavericks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20009628/sml-not-detecting-os-on-os-x-mavericks)
- [How do I install a working version of Standard ML on Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19024116/how-do-i-install-a-working-version-of-standard-ml)

But perhaps you should be asking that question instead and not this one. :)

Otherwise, try and set the current username to 'Cadenzah' instead of 'cadenzah' so it matches the capitalisation of your user directory. Unix filesystems tend to be case sensitive. Even though MacOS is not, by default, this may cause some conflicts in software that don't respect local filesystem laws.

Comment: Actually I encountered the problem of not detecting OS on MacOS, but I solved it by googling, thank god.
By the way, my current username starts with 'c' not 'C', so I wonder if that is the problem for not detecting the user directory.
I guess I should just remove the SML/NJ and re-install again.

Comment: Oh, I wrote my user directory name is 'C'adenzah. That was my mistake. Sorry about that.

Comment: SML/NJ is bundled in an old-fashioned way. That makes it hard to install from scratch. Fortunately most operating system package managers do the ugly bits for you, including Homebrew.

Comment: So kind tip for me! Gotta install it again with package manager.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

If you are having this issue and can't resolve it by using homebrew to install, try setting the environment variable `SMLHOME_DIR` to the installation directory. This may resolve some "File not found" errors.

Example:

```
% pwd
/usr/local/smlnj
% ls
MLRISC/  bin/   cml/     doc/  ml-burg/  ml-lpt/   nlffi/  smlnj-lib/            license.html
base/    ckit/  config/  lib/  ml-lex/   ml-yacc/  null    trace-debug-profile/
% export SMLNJ_HOME=/usr/local/smlnj/
```

You can then add that to your `.zshrc`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same issue by exporting `SMLNJ_HOME` mentioned in SML's MacOS  installation documentation.

Execute:

`echo 'export SMLNJ_HOME="/usr/local/smlnj"' >> $HOME/.bash_profile`

Then, source it into your current command line environment:

`source $HOME/.bash_profile`

SML is then capable of loading extra functions from the core library:

```
Standard ML of New Jersey v110.79 [built: Sun Oct  4 14:45:06 2015]
- List.nth;
[autoloading]
[library $SMLNJ-BASIS/basis.cm is stable]
[library $SMLNJ-BASIS/(basis.cm):basis-common.cm is stable]
[autoloading done]
val it = fn : 'a list * int -> 'a
```