# How to remove SML/NJ 110.75 from Mac OS X Mavericks?

Tags: osx-mavericks, uninstallation, smlnj

I installed SML/NJ 110.75 on Mac OS X Mavericks following [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19030511/1382487) by @MisterSpock. The install initially failed but it was a simple matter of editing a config file, as instructed [here](http://users-cs.au.dk/danvy/dIFP09/smlnj/Mac-OS-X-Snow-Leopard-install-smlnj.txt), to fix that. After the install, I [noticed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19105647/1382487) that [a binary for SML/NJ 110.76 is available](http://www.smlnj.org/dist/working/110.76/index.html) and I installed that. Now, how do I remove the previous installation of SML/NJ 110.75?

Answer (score 3):

You can remove it by using the terminal to delete the installation directory:

```
$ sudo rm -rf /usr/local/smlnj
```

And, after that, installing SML/NJ will put a new copy there.

Note: additionally, you may wish to remove the man pages:

```
/usr/local/share/man/man1/ml-antlr.1
/usr/local/share/man/man1/ml-build.1
/usr/local/share/man/man1/ml-ulex.1
/usr/local/share/man/man1/ml-makedepend.1
/usr/local/share/man/man1/sml.1
/usr/local/share/man/man7/smlnj.7
```